# Would I really want to return the minimum date?

Tags: c#, datetime, resharper, default-value

An old work colleague used to quote his father about tools, "You have to be smarter than it."

In the code below, Resharper is telling me, "Value assigned is not used in any execution path" (pointing to the first line). If I accept its offer of help, dt is not assigned a value ("today").

Is this a case where "I have to be smarter than it" and ignore their warning, or is this a case where the tool is smarter than me, and I'm just not understanding it?

My take on the situation is that if the if statement fails, the current date is returned (the default value I want), but if I acquiesce to Resharper's "demands" it would return the default value for Datetime, which is the minimum date, which I assume is something like 7/4/1776 or 1/1/0000 or so.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
if (!(DateTime.TryParse(substr, out dt))) {
    using (var dtpDlgForm = new ReturnDate("Please select the Date that the file was created:")) {
        if (dtpDlgForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            dt = dtpDlgForm.ReturnVal;
        } 
    }
}
return dt;
```

Comment: This is a case where I would suggest you use multiple returns. It's more obvious if you replace the last line with `return DateTime.Now` and the line in the middle of the using with `return dtpDlgForm.ReturnVal`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your *intended* logic allows for three possible return values of `DateTime` (in order of preference):

1. The parsed value of `substr`.
2. The value selected from the dialog.
3. The current date and time.

You can implement this logic by having separate `return` statements that are executed when their condition succeeds:

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(substr, out dt))
    return dt;

using (var dtpDlgForm = new ReturnDate(
    "Please select the Date that the file was created:")) 
{
    if (dtpDlgForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        return dtpDlgForm.ReturnVal;
}

return DateTime.Now;
```

**Edit**: For an explanation on why you should not assign a value to a variable that will be used as an `out` parameter, refer to [Mark Byers’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10952501/1149773).

Comment: Thanks; all the answers were great. I marked this as "the" correct one, because even if the date is not sussed out by the file name, and the user then closes the "dialog" form prompting him/her for the date with a dialog result other than "OK" it returns "today" rather than 12/7/1941 or whenever.

Comment: Small niggling point: the tryParse line needs another right paren in place of semicolon.

Comment: @ClayShannon: As  Mike Bantegui [mentioned above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952470/would-i-really-want-to-return-the-minimum-date/10952537#comment14295586_10952470), this is a case where multiple `return` statements may be preferable since they simplify the flow of the method – you can simply assume that the method’s execution will stop as soon as any `DateTime`-determining condition succeeds. Thanks for pointing out the `TryParse` typo; now fixed.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  As is almost *always* the case, ReSharper is correct.  The issue is that as @JonSenchnya answered, DateTime.TryParse() always sets your `dt` variable before returning.  That's a requirement of an `out` parameter.  Thus your initial value of `dt` is indeed never being returned.

Comment: @RossPatterson: How is the answer “wrong”? Does it give undesirable results under any circumstance? Does it state something that is factually incorrect? Does it assign an “initial value of `dt` [that] is indeed never being returned”? I admittedly did not repeat the explanation given in plenty of the other answers, just for the sake of avoiding redundancy, but the solution provided is complete and correct.

Comment: @Douglas There's no path in the original code that returns the current date, because DateTime.TryParse is *always* going to set `dt` to some value.  As the correct answer says, that will be `DateTime.MinValue` if the parse fails.

Comment: @RossPatterson: The original code in the OP’s question was erroneous in that respect (thus the motivation for posting the question in the first place), but the issue has been addressed in my answer’s code. It does not make a difference what value will be assigned to `dt` in case of parse failure, since it is ignored.

Comment: Yes, I believe Douglas' code is just what the OP (me) ordered: If option A works, I get the date value from the file name. If not, and option B works (prompting the user for the date), I get that date. If both options fail, I get the default that I want ("today"), not the DateTime minimum value, which I don't want.

Comment: @ClayShannon gets the last word, since it's his question in the first place.

Answer (score 53):

The answer you accepted shows what you *should* be doing but doesn't explain *why* Resharper complains in the first place. Since this explanation could be useful for others who find your question, here it is:

You *should* follow Resharper's advice and change the first line to:

```
DateTime dt;
```

This declares the variable `dt` but does not assign any value to it. There is no need to assign a value here because it will be definitely assigned on the next line due to the [`out` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx). From the documentation:

> Although variables passed as `out` arguments do not have to be initialized before being passed, **the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns**.

Emphasis mine. Assigning the value `DateTime.Now` is unnecessary and misleading because this value will never be used.

> My take on the situation is that if the if statement fails, the current date is returned

That is not what your code does. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx):

> result: When this method returns, contains the DateTime value equivalent to the date and time contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, **or MinValue if the conversion failed.**

With the code you posted if the parse fails then `dt` will contain the value `DateTime.MinValue` and not the value `DateTime.Now` that you assigned.

Comment: +1 Very good explanation. In this kind of situation I'd be grateful to have ReSharper on my side! I need to go through all my TryParse usages now.... :(

Answer (score 20):

It's because you're assigning a value to dt and then passing it in as an [out param](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).  If a variable is passed in as an out param:

- It must be assigned a value inside that function before being used within it
- It must be assigned a value before that function returns

In your case, you can fix the message from ReSharper message by changing your first line to:

```
DateTime dt;
```

> My take on the situation is that if the if statement fails, the
>   current date is returned

This is not true.  It will always return [DateTime.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx), regardless of the value of the DateTime object you pass in.

From [MSDN - DateTime.TryParse(string, out DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx):

> *result*
>
> Type: System.DateTime%
>
> **When this method returns, [result] contains** the DateTime value
>   equivalent to the date and time contained in s, if the conversion
>   succeeded, or **[MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) if the conversion failed**. The conversion
>   fails if the s parameter is null, is an empty string (""), or does not
>   contain a valid string representation of a date and time. This
>   parameter is passed uninitialized.

(Emphasis added)

Answer (score 8):

An `out` parameter has always a value assigned to it. It is always guaranteed that the called function assigns a value to it before returning. Therefore it will overwrite the value initially assigned in any case.

Answer (score 7):

The point here is about using [out parameter modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx):

> Although variables passed as out arguments do not have to be initialized before being passed, the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns.

`DateTime.TryParse` will assign a default value to `dt` anyways, and if it cannot parse `substr`, the resulting `dt` will have the value of the minimum datetime.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime.TryParse(substr, out dt);
```

can return false but it will still modify `dt`. It will try to complete `dt` to the best of its ability, initializing some of the values as best as it can. When using the `out` modifier in c#, you are telling the program to initialize it, and you should not expect to retain the value you pass in.

What you could do is

```
DateTime dt;
if (!(DateTime.TryParse(substr, out dt))) {
    using (var dtpDlgForm = new ReturnDate("Please select the Date that the file was created:")) {
        if (dtpDlgForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            dt = dtpDlgForm.ReturnVal;
        } 
        else {
            dt = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}

return dt;
```

Comment: I think your code will return today if the TryParse succeeds. That's not correct, if TryParse succeeds, the parsed value should be returned.

Comment: Oh my god you're totally right. changed my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

This code would make the warning go away. But I think Douglas' answer is easier to read.

```
DateTime dt;
if (!(DateTime.TryParse(substr, out dt))) {
    dt = DateTime.Now;
    using (var dtpDlgForm = new ReturnDate("Please select the Date that the file was created:")) {
        if (dtpDlgForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            dt = dtpDlgForm.ReturnVal;
        } 
    }
}
return dt;
```